# Ubuntu Backup - how to backup to server

Tags: server, backup

Good morning,

I am trying to setup my Ubuntu machine to backup to my Ubuntu server.  When I goto backup, I cannot go into any of my none of my folders from the backup app to direct it to back up there.  Any help would be great.  Thank you.

Best,

Bobby

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Deja-Dup you click on Storage location in the left column, then click on the down arrow in the top box.  Scroll down and select "Local Folder".  Then, back on the main screen, click on Choose Folder and find where your network share is mounted.

I found it a little confusing at first to look for my network share in Local Folders too....

Comment: Thank you so much for replying.  Sorry about the delay in reply. Been a bit busy over the weekend.  (so much to do, so little time.) I am a little confused at this myself....  I think I figured it out.  I needed to use "Custom Location" and then opened my location in the File Manager and copy and pasted it in.  It looks like it is backing up to that location at least I hope.  Thank you very much for you help.  I really appreciate it.  I do have another question.  Is there a way to back it up twice in two different locations.  For example, I have it backed up on my server and also on the cloud

Comment: like to a dropbox or to any other cloud service.  (it doesn't really matter which one.. I just know once I put it in the dropbox folder, it is just another copy on my computer as well as in dropbox which is taking up more space on my drive which is one thing I am not a big fan of when using dropbox folders.  I just want to have redundancy because this is very important information that I do not want to lose.  (The reason it is on my server is for two reasons, for others working on the same project to be able to access it and also so there is a backup. But I would really like to have a cloud

Comment: backup as well.  Thank you again for you help... a side note using this forum, how do I make a line break when adding a comment.  I tried to use <br/> but it isn't breaking the lines up.  Thank you again for you help!!